# Set action on detailDisclosureButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have set UITableViewCell in my app.

```
productsCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;//productCell is of type UITableViewCell
```

Previously for this accessoryAction property was used. But now its deprecated.

How to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Implement this method in your delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

`indexPath` will point on the cell which accessory cell was tapped.

Or try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryTapped)];
[cell.accessoryView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

Comment: I did that. But method is not being called. Make sure, I am using a single cell of UITableViewCell. I am not using UITableView.

Comment: Are you using cell without table?

Comment: Yes. I am using it without cell. In my requirement tableView doesn't fit.

Comment: Then I can only suggest to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `cell.accessoryView`.